# Checking if a file is writable in Perl

Tags: bash, perl

What would be Perl equivalent of this bash script?

```
for file in *
do 
    if [ -w $file ] ; then 
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

I am trying to see which files are writable.

Comment: How about also `-w` ? See `perldoc -f -w`

Comment: Did you try `-w` before asking here? :-)

Comment: @Dave Cross, Bad advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be the [`-w` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html):

```
for my $file (glob '*') {   
    if (-w $file) {
        print "$file\n";
    }   
}
```